# LINQ aggregating multiple IEnumerables into one?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a Dictionary defined as `<int, IEnumerable<char>>`.  Lets say the data is populated like:

```
1, a b c d e
2, f g h i j
3, k l m n o
```

If I have an IEnumerable consisting of 1 & 3, what would the LINQ look like to return `'a b c d e k l m n o'` (assuming space represents an iteration).

Comment: Could you post that as an answer? Anything related to SelectMany could be interesting since that function is confusing :)

Comment: Cheat-sheet: `Select` = "map", `SelectMany` = "flatmap", `Where` = "filter", `Concat` = "append" -- this is what I use in my own head ;-)

Comment: @Michael: in my experience, developers that hadn't gotten familiar with SelectMany had an easier time when using the 'compound from' of comprehension syntax - for instance, in the SelectMany samples of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336758

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SelectMany is indeed what you want, but IMHO it's more readable to use the comprehension syntax and let it do the mapping for you, so something like:

```
var dict = ... // dictionary
var keys = ... // enumerable with 1 and 3 in it
var result = from key in keys
             from val in dict[key]
             select val;
```

It's easier (again, IMHO) to toss an 'orderby' in there as well if/as needed.

Of course, if you find the extension method version simpler to read/parse, then by all means, use that instead. :)

Answer (score 3):

If you want a KeyNotFoundException if a key is not found:

```
IEnumerable<char> result = keys.SelectMany(key => d[key]);
```

If you want to silently ignore keys that are not found:

```
IEnumerable<char> result = keys.Where(key => d.ContainsKey(key))
                               .SelectMany(key => d[key]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have

```
var someEnumerables = new Dictionary<int, IEnumerable<char>>();
```

then

```
// Flattened will be an enumeration of the values ordered first by the key
var flattened = someEnumerables.OrderBy(kvp => kvp.Key).SelectMany(kvp => kvp.Value)
```

Comment: +0; correctly shows the use of `SelectMany`, but doesn't address OP's requirement to filter by a list of keys.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `Where` clause to filter the keys contained in the dictionary, and a `SelectMany` clause to get a single enumerable list from each list contained in the dictionary.

```
Dictionary<int, IEnumerable<char>> dict; // contains all of your key-value pairs
IEnumerable<int> keys; // contains the keys you want to filter by

IEnumerable<char> data = dict.Where(kvp => keys.Contains(kvp.Key))
                             .SelectMany(kvp => kvp.Value);

// or, alternatively:

IEnumerable<char> data = keys.SelectMany(i => dict[i]);
```

Note that the second query will throw an exception if you have a key in the `keys` enumerable that doesn't exist in your dictionary.

Comment: You really should be building off of the `keys` collection rather than going through all of the items in the dictionary.

Comment: Right you are; I added a more succinct way of doing it, with a disclaimer.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in your comment, you can use a `SelectMany` to aggregate an `IEnumerable` of `IEnumerable`s into a single `IEnumerable`. However, you can also use `Concat` to combine two separate collections into a single selection (or you can chain it to combine as many as you'd like).

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear if you want only the 1 & 3 lines or all of them (1, 2 and 3).  Here's the solution for both

```
Dictionary<int, string> map = ...;
// 1 and 3 only
IEnumerable<char> result1 = map
  .Where(x => x.Key == 1 || x.Key == 3)
  .OrderyBy(x => x.Key)
  .SelectMany(x => x.Value)

// All
IEnumerable<char> result2 = map
  .OrderyBy(x => x.Key)
  .SelectMany(x => x.Value)
```